# Implementations of GRGPF Clustering algorithm

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, large-data

I am looking for source that implements the Clustering algorithm found in Ganti et.al. "Clustering Large Datasets in Arbitrary Metric Spaces."  IN particular, I have a large data problem that I seek to cluster (so it is a one pass cluster problem) and I do not have binary operators on the space (so finding "average" elements between elements is not an option).

I am agnostic to language (although I would prefer a simple I/O mechanism).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors? This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: I did.  They do not have an implementation to share.  The programming aspect comes from implementing the BIRCH* search tree.  I was wondering about viable implementations.  In particular, what form of data structure do people implement the search tree with?